# Desktop notification from background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm beginner in chrome extensions development. I'm trying to show desktop notifications when my background script finishes some of its methods but i don't know how i can request permissions for this. Is there any way to accomplish this task?

It can be done using content script, but I want to show notifications by background script, without background page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add notifications to your manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "notifications","management"]
```

You can then call

```
webkitNotifications.createNotification('images/message48.png', title, message);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i miss this permission in my manifest, decision was so simple