# Generate Notifications in Background from messages in a WebExtension

Tags: javascript, notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So I am learning about the web-extension world by developing an extension for Mozilla FireFox.

As part of my extension, my primary content script will generate and send a message, using the `browser.runtime.sendMessage()` method:

```
console.log("<extension> is active.");
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    notify: "<extension> is now active."
});
```

I then have a background javascript page that is listening for messages (using the `runtime.onMessage.addListener()` event) that is *supposed* to create a Notification object with the message text. It also gracefully handles requests for notification permissions like so:

```
function handleNotifications(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('Notify message generated by content script.');
    // Check if notification permissions have been granted
    if (Notification.permission === "granted"){
        // If yes, then create the notification
        var notification = new Notification(title, {
            icon: img,
            body: request.notify,
        });
    }

    // Otherwise, we must ask the user for permission
    else if (Notification.permission !== "denied"){
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission){
            // If the user accepts, then create notifications
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification(title, {
                    icon: img,
                    body: request.notify,
                });
            }
        });

    //If for some reason the user has *denied* notifications, alert them
    } else {
        alert("You have chosen to disable notifications. <extension> will still work, but will not inform you of outcomes.");
    }
}

// Create listener for messages from content script
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleNotifications);
```

I've re-written the background code from the ground up once according to the specs from the MDN pages [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/Notification). I also googled around and made sure my manifest.json has `notifications` permissions as suggested on [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852862/desktop-notification-from-background-script).

Currently, my code will execute nominally as far as I can tell; it generates alerts and logs, and will create notifications when they are called *in the content scripts*, but not in the background. My best guess is that the background listener never actually fires, but I am not sure how to debug that aside from the fact that I can say the `console.log` line I put in the background snippet above never appears in the developer console.

Comment: So you are trying to create a notification by sending a message from your background script to your background script?

Comment: No, the message comes from content.js and background.js is listening.

Comment: Dumb question, you did define your background script in the manifest right?

Comment: Yes, I have. I has also listed my content.js and jquery scripts under the scripts section. If you'd like, I can paste the relevant sections.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and the background console message fires for me, but not your notification.  So maybe the issue is in your manifest  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/create for fixing notification.

Comment: So, could you clarify the difference between Notification() and notifications.create()? They seem to be redundant.